# pls 00905 object is invalid

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace procedure p_update_project_status(v_project_id in number(10)) is
declare
    v_bid_file_status number(2);
    v_bid_form_status number(2);
    v_supplier_status number(2);
begin
    select status into v_bid_file_status from PROJECT_FILE where type = 0 and associated_project_id = v_project_id;
    select status into v_bid_form_status from PROJECT_FILE where type = 1 and associated_project_id = v_project_id; 
    select status into v_supplier_status from SUPPLIER_INFO where associated_project_id = v_project_id; 
    if( (v_bid_file_status = 3) and (v_bid_form_status = 3) and (v_supplier_status = 3) ) then
        update PROJECT_INFO set status = 3 where id = v_project_id;
    else
        update PROJECT_INFO set status = 0 where id = v_project_id;
    end if;
end;
```

I execute the procedure,but it's invalid, I have tried my best to correct it, but still invalid.I don't know where is going wrong.Please help me

Comment: Try removing `declare` keyword

Comment: If you do a `show errors` after running this, you'd see the error message

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name please, can you explain that a litte bit, i don't know this instruction. Thanks

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e16604/ch_twelve041.htm#sthref2263

Answer (score 0):

DECLARE keyword is not necessary here. You need it only if youre running an anonymous block. Remove that and it should compile.